# How to make response card buttons working in facebook chat for Lex?

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, amazon-lex

I have configured response cards for prompt message on Lex console, I am able to get the card on messenger as well but when I click on any button it's not working.
It sends the value attached to the button, but I get no response. If I enter the response manually then I get the results immediately.
Do we need to configure something else to get buttons in the response cards working?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by checking/ticking the "messaging_postbacks" events in the Webhooks in messenger settings in the Facebook app.

[image]

Comment: You should also subscribe for message_optins for buttons to work

Comment: @Saurabh, buttons are working without message_optins

Answer (score 0):

Only responsive cards created in the lambda function work for me this way, and the standard one created in intent is not even displayed.

Enable message_optins didn't help.

Comment: Understood. You need to fill in all the required cells: Image URL, Title, Subtitle.